# Linux how to trace what dependencies are checked by a configure script

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, gstreamer, configure

I am compiling a few programs from source, when running configure it lists some dependencies that are not met, therefore the .so for the function will not be built. The error messages and documentation are sparse on details of what is missing or what other headers etc to install.

How do I use configure and make to trace what tests are being run by configure and dependencies are not met.

For example in gstreamer-bad, the configure spits out

```
 configure: *** Plug-ins with dependencies that will NOT be built:
hls
```

On checking the docs site, it has a basic reference to

```
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins.html 
hls HTTP Live Streaming (HLS)   gst-plugins-bad 1.9.0.1
    hlsdemux    HTTP Live Streaming demuxer
    hlssink HTTP Live Streaming sink
```

but no link as to what external lib it needs. So I had a look in ./configure & configure.log, but nothing that points directly to the *.h, *.c, *so it is looking for.

I did find reference to `ac_config_files=" ext/hls/Makefile "`and in that file I find reference to the files that will be created, but I could not find a ref to the dependency check. So then checking the include in the *.c,*.h files again shows nothing obvious.

Is there a method to start a backtrace to figure out what dependency I am looking for? am I looking in the right places or is there a basic step I am missing to give me more detailed info?
`

Comment: Sometimes `SHELL='bash -x' bash -x ./configure ...` helps. That tells bash to run the `configure` script and print each command as it runs it, and sets `SHELL` so that any makefiles and subprocesses will also run bash with the `-x` flag.

Comment: @JonathanWakely This should be the answer.

Comment: @yugr added as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `SHELL='bash -x' bash -x ./configure ...` helps. That tells bash to run the `configure` script and print each command as it runs it, and sets `SHELL` so that any makefiles and subprocesses will also run bash with the `-x` flag.